# F# Error: Value cannot be reference and If Else statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, f#

I am converting C# code to F# code. For some reason, the compiler does not like how I call methods in the F# file.

I don't know why the `ReturnClosestInList` and `findYGivenTwoPointsInSameGraph` cannot be referenced. For the `if then else`, should I use a `let` to bind the `finish`? I don't know why it detects it as `bool` instead of `int`.  Anyone know why I got these errors and perhaps can suggest a better way to write this?

This is my C# code:

```
    // find point on graph with given Rc
    private Coordinate GetXY(Dictionary<double, double> cons)
    {
        if (cons.ContainsKey(input))
            return new Coordinate(input, cons[input]);
        else
        {
            //Rc is not found, use interpolation to find point at given Rc.
            List<double> index = ReturnClosestInList(new List<double>(cons.Keys), 0, cons.Count - 1);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("index1 " + index[0]);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("index2 " + index[1]);
            return FindClosest(index, cons);
        }
    }

    //formula to find y, given 2 points in the same graph
    private Coordinate FindClosest(List<double> index, Dictionary<double, double> cons)
    {
        double y = cons[index[0]] + ((input - index[0]) / (index[1] - index[0])) * (cons[index[1]] - cons[index[0]]);
        return new Coordinate(input, y);
    }

    //formula to find y, given 2 points from 2 graphs
    private Coordinate FindClosest2(Coordinate p1, Coordinate p2)
    {
        double y = p1.Y + ((givenLine - p1.X) / (p2.X - p1.X)) * (p2.Y - p1.Y);
        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("y is " + y);
        return new Coordinate(givenLine, y);
    }

    //binary search for 2 closest Rc value in the given vi graph.
    private List<double> ReturnClosestInList(List<double> allKey, int begin, int end)
    {
        if (end >= begin)
        {
            int mid = begin + (end - begin) / 2;
            if (allKey[mid] > input) return ReturnClosestInList(allKey, begin, mid - 1);
            return ReturnClosestInList(allKey, mid + 1, end);
        }
        if (end < 0) end = begin + 1;
        if (begin < 0) begin = end + 1;
        if (end > allKey.Count - 1) end = begin - 1;
        if (begin > allKey.Count - 1) begin = end - 1;
        return new List<double> { allKey[begin], allKey[end] };
    }
```

This is my current F# code.

```
let Keys(map: Map<_, _>) =
    seq{
        for KeyValue(key) in map do
            yield key
    }


let findPointXYGivenRc (cons : Map<double, double>) (input : double) = 
    let output = if (cons.ContainsKey(input)) then
                    let c = new Coordinate(cons.[input], input)
                    c
                 else
                    let list = ReturnClosestInList Keys cons 0 (cons.Count - 1) input
                    let c = findYGivenTwoPointsInSameGraph list cons input
                    c                       
    output

let findYGivenTwoPointsInSameGraph (index : Map<int, double>) (cons : Map<double, double>) (input : double) =
    let y = cons.[index.[0]] + (input - index.[0]) / (index.[1] - index.[0]) * (cons.[index.[1]] - cons.[index.[0]])
    let c = new Coordinate(input, y)
    c

let findYGivenTwoPointsFromTwoGraphs (p1 : Coordinate) (p2: Coordinate) (givenLine : double) = 
    let y = p1.Y + (givenLine - p1.X) / (p2.X - p1.X) * (p2.Y - p1.Y);
    let c = new Coordinate(givenLine, y)
    c

let rec ReturnClosestInList (allKey : List<double>) (start : int) (finish : int) (input : double)= 
    if(finish >= start) then
        let mid = start + (finish - start) / 2
        if(allKey.[mid] > input) then
            ReturnClosestInList allKey start (mid - 1) input
        else ReturnClosestInList allKey (start + 1) mid input

    finish = if finish < 0 then 
                start + 1
             else finish
```

This is my first error

[image: first error]

This is my second error:

[image: second error]

Comment: Sorry, the `GetXY` method in C# should corresponds to the `findPointXYGivenRc` in F#.

Comment: `FinsClosest` should corresponds to `findYGivenTwoPointsInSameGraph`

Comment: `FinsClosest2` should corresponds to `findYGivenTwoPointsFromTwoGraphs`

Comment: In F# order of definitions matters. A function has to be defined _before_ it's referenced, not after.

Comment: In F#, you must bind a value or define a type before you use it. So, basically just reverse the order of your function definitions.

Comment: Welcome to the F# community. Regarding the second error, `finish = if...` is not a binding or assignment -- it's an equality comparison. The parameter `finish` is immutable, so you cannot assign a new value to it. If you're trying to return `finish` as the result then just remove the `finish = ` and the function will return the last expression as the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first error where it can't "find" `ReturnClosestInList` is because ordering matters in F# code. `ReturnClosestInList` has to be defined before `findPointXYGivenRc` and so on:

```
let g () = f 12 // ERROR: 'f' isn't known to 'g' right here

let f x = ()

let h () = f 12 // Compiles: 'f' is already defined and known
```

You have three options:

1. Re-order your F# functions in source to be in a top-down ordering. Things are defined before they are used.
2. If you have [mutually recursive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/functions/recursive-functions-the-rec-keyword#mutually-recursive-functions) functions you can define them as a set with `let...and` as in the example documentation. This isn't the case in the snippet you provided, but it may come up in the future.
3. Consider using [recursive modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/modules#recursive-modules) when you have several things that all inter-depend on one another.

Your second error is a little more confusing, but you have two problems:

1. Your `if(finish >= start) then` clause has no corresponding `else`.
2. Your use of `finish = ...` is saying "the value finish should be equal to the following expression".

The first sub-problem here is what leads to the compile error. An `if` in F# that doesn't have an `else` returns `unit` (same as `void`). But you can't do that here, you need to return an actual value. Otherwise there's no indicator that anything completed/succeeded as you've defined it.

The second one comes up immediately after you fix the first one. Do you expect to return a `bool` here? If you do, then you can leave it. But if you don't, then you should just make the `if` expression the overall return.

What I *think* your function should look like is this:

```
let rec ReturnClosestInList (allKey : List<double>) (start : int) (finish : int) (input : double)= 
    if(finish >= start) then
        let mid = start + (finish - start) / 2
        if(allKey.[mid] > input) then
            ReturnClosestInList allKey start (mid - 1) input
        else ReturnClosestInList allKey (start + 1) mid input
    else
        if finish < 0 then 
            start + 1
        else
            finish
```

This resolves both problems by making it a recursive function that returns a value and making it return an `int` rather than a `bool`.